# how to restore defaults in altium-designer?

Tags: altium

how to restore project options--> default prints tab to default
the **set to installation defaults**  button is dimmed .
or at least restoring the whole project

thanks

Comment: Does your license show as being in good order (and valid for the mode you are using it in)?

Comment: Odd, the Set to Installation Defaults on the Default prints page on my installation is dimmed out too.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be no direct reset procedure for altium if anyone knows please tell us .

but i've tried something and reached to reset **default prints** tab

- create new project .
- move files from old project to new project
- open new project configuration and ...hah new **default prints** without any mark

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean "How do I reset the Altium Designer configuration to the installation defaults?" but refer to this https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/how-do-i-reset-the-altium-designer-configuration-to-the-installation-defaults